# ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'unittest.main' python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a small unittest program writing in Python. It has problem in "import unittest". Here is the error message(I run it in Pycharm and mac catalina os):

> import unittest   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/**init**.py",
>   line 64, in 
>       from .main import TestProgram, main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unittest.main'

Process finished with exit code

It has same error when I run it in Python3 command line. No problem to run it in Python(python2).
The program worked early this week on python3. 
Here is my program:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import random

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def numberToString(self, number):
        digitNames = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
        result = ""
        while number > 0:
            currentDigit = number % 10  # modulus operator gives remainder after integer division
            # in this case it is the rightmost digit
            result = digitNames[currentDigit] + ' ' + result
            number = number // 10  # integer division throws away the remainder
        return result

    def test_something(self):
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
        for i in range(1, 2):
            a = random.randint(1, 65535)
            b = random.randint(1, 65535)
            browser.get("http://www.math.com/students/calculators/source/basic.htm")
            aSpell = self.numberToString(a).split()
            bSpell = self.numberToString(b).split()
            for spell in aSpell:
                browser.find_element_by_name(spell).send_keys(" " + spell)
            browser.find_element_by_name("plus").send_keys(" +")
            for spell in bSpell:
                browser.find_element_by_name(spell).send_keys(" " + spell)
            browser.find_element_by_name("DoIt").send_keys(" =")

            self.assertEqual(eval(browser.find_element_by_name("Input").get_attribute("value")), a + b)
        browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It's possibly path problem I guess, but I don't know how to fix it. Do I need to reinstall python3? My current version is 3.7.

Comment: you can install unittest using this `pip install unittest`

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam: unittest comes with Python. You should not attempt to install it with pip.

Answer (score -3):

I got this problem because my unittest was not in the same folder than my local imports.

For take your local import you can do :

```html
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'../')
from main import MyFunction1, MyFunction2
```

If your import is a folder before your unittest file